# SQL inner join error with PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've been having some trouble re-rewriting this SQL statement to get it to work with PDO but it keeps giving me the error

## 1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'venues'

Tried many things and was just wondering if anyone out there had an idea as to what is wrong Thanks again.

**SQL statement:**

```
SELECT tournaments.tour_id, tournaments.price, tournaments.description, venues.venue_name 
FROM tournaments, venues 
INNER JOIN venues on tournaments.venue_id = venues.id
```

**Tables:** tournaments, venues

## tournaments table

[image: Tournaments structure]

## venues table

[image: venues structure]

In my actual PHP code, i'm accessing it like so.

```
$statement = $pdo->query($sql);
if($statement->rowCount()){
        while ($dnn = $statement->fetch_object()) {
                echo "{$dnn->tour_id} {$dnn->venue_name}<br/>";
        }
} else {
        echo "no results";
}
```

Comment: It should be `FROM tournaments`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with below query

```
SELECT tournaments.tour_id, tournaments.price, tournaments.description, 
venues.venue_name 
FROM tournaments
INNER JOIN venues on tournaments.venue_id = venues.id
```

> In Your query "FROM tournaments, venues" is the issue

Comment: Ahh, I forgot that on inner join you don't need to identify both tables. Thank you, sir!

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT tournaments.tour_id, tournaments.price, tournaments.description, 
venues.venue_name 
FROM tournaments
INNER JOIN venues on tournaments.venue_id = venues.id
```

`FROM tournaments, venues INNER JOIN venues` this is not the way to inner join.  Inner joining on the same table with different columns venue_id is tournament table but not in venues table. This is the reason for your Error.